# Need more registers for bit extraction

Tags: assembly, x86, bit-manipulation

I'm currently working on a program that extracts the sign, mantissa, and exponent of a floating point using in-line assembly. I am required to use the `bextr` command as well. I feel as if I have most of it down, except I'm out of 32 bit registers to use. Is there any way to free up a 32-bit register?

The code is:

```c
void MyFloat::unpackFloat(float f) {
    //this function must be written in inline assembly
    //extracts the fields of f into sign, exponent, and mantissa
    __asm__(
    //eax is f (the floating point number)
    //ecx is used to keep track of the range of bits
    //ebx is sign of the floating point
    //edx is exponent of the floating point
    // is mantissa of the floating point
 
      //extract sign
      "movb $1, %%ch;" //defines how many bits to read, ch is the lower 16 bits for ecx
      "movb $31, %%cl;" //defines what bit to start at, cl is the lower 8 bits for ecx
      "bextr %%ecx, %%eax, %%ebx;" //the range of bits from ecx, eax (floating point) is where you extract from, ebx is the destination
      "xor %%ecx, %%ecx;"

      //extract exponent
      "movb $8, %%ch;" //read 8 bits
      "movb $24, %%cl;" //start reading from bit 24
      "bextr %%ecx, %%eax, %%edx;"
      "xor %%ecx, %%ecx;"
 
      //extract mantissa
      "movb $23, %%ch;" //read 23 bits
      "movb $1, %%cl;" //start reading from bit 1
      "bextr %%ecx, %%eax, %%????":



      "=c" (sign), "=d" (exponent), "=b" (mantissa):
 
      "a" (f):
 
      "cc"
 
    );
}//unpackFloat
```

One potential solution I was thinking is to just have the mantissa be ecx. What do you guys think? So the final line for the mantissa would be: `bextr %%ecx, %%eax, %%ecx`:

Comment: Do it in multiple inline assembly statements, each of which is below the register limit.  Though it looks like you still have `esi`, `edi`, and `ebp` left.

Comment: Also you can extract into `ecx` for which you already specified the output constraint although you have the sign and the mantissa swapped. Note you can just load `ecx` with a constant, you don't need to zero it and then load `cl` and `ch` separately. Since this inline asm is specific to gcc you might as well just use the `__builtin_ia32_bextr_u32` instead.

Comment: Are you doing this for performance reasons?  `mov $0x011f, %ecx` would be much more efficient.  Also, extracting the top bit is just `mov %%eax, %%ebx` ; `shr $31, %%ebx`, which you could and should do in plain C.  Or leave it at the top but mask off the rest to get a 0 or INT_MIN, or just test the original bit-pattern for negative.  Also, the mantissa is the bottom 23 bits of the register, starting with bit `0`.  `and $(1<<23)-1, %%eax`, or `mantissa = f & ((1uL<<23)-1)` in pure C to get the compiler to emit an instruction like that for you.